# How do I prevent the 2 apps from altering shared data at the same time? even if I already used "select for update"?

Tags: java, postgresql

I have 2 apps with a shared Database. Essentially, these 2 apps are trying to update a row every x seconds. The table looks like this:

```
| host_name | acquired | attribute  | 
| --------- | -------- | ---------- |
| app1      | TRUE     | 'xyz'      |
```

In the table above, the attribute has to be unique. The host_name can change depending on which app acquired it. So, if app2 has the acquired the attribute, it will hold that attribute for x number of seconds, then it will set the acquired to false, and both app2 and app1 will race to get that acquire the particular attribute again.

For this, I have used the "select for update" statement of postgres, so that if app2 acquires the attribute, it locks the row and app1 couldn't change it until the lock is released. I initially thought, the "select for update" is bullet proof, but I was wrong. A few days ago, the lock didn't work. I assumed app1 and app2 got the  lock at the same time. I was wondering if  I could enhance this so that it doesn't happen next time. Any suggestions?

Comment: "*app1 and app2 got the lock at the same time*" - that's impossible. Postgres (in fact _no_ DBMS) allows two different transactions to acquire a lock on the same row.

Answer (score 0):

on your update statement, try something like this (change ID to your primary key which is hopefully integer or bigint)

```
select * from my_table
where attribute='xyz'
and pg_try_advisory_lock(id)
for update
```

Don't forget to run

```
pg_advisory_unlock()
```

when you're done with the row.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is bullet proof. It's just software. You can try a more optimistic approach.
Add a 'update-counter' row to your table.
Before update the row, you read the row to get the current counter value and in your update statement, add a where condition to ensure, that you only update the row if the counter wasn't change by another process

```
Update my_table set x=y, counter=counter+1 where counter=read_before
```

After executing, check if a row was changed. If yes, everything is ok. If not, do whatever you  do in case of failure.